# EMR vs KCL on aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

We are planning to consume messages from Kinesis stream. We need to process event data one by one (no windowing, no aggregation), and we could see multiple options to read data from kinesis stream:

Kinesis consumer library

Lambda function

Spark/Flink Streaming on EMR

Can someone share some light on when one option should be favored over other?

Thanks In Advance